# Noncontractible domain with trivial cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Can you exhibit an example of a noncontractible domain in R^n with the d-th cohomology groups trivial for all d greater or equal to 1?
Thank you

Comment: Didn't you ask a really similar question the other day? And didn't you get a really similar answer? 

Comment: In the other question I need a noncontractible domain with Euler characteristic equal to 1.
But only now I can understand that the  older question and the new are related in some sense. Sorry, I'm not strong on this subject!

Comment: @Flux: Here is a general principle to remember: If $X$ is a finite-dimensional countable cell-complex, then $X$ is homotopy-equivalent to a domain in ${\mathbb R}^n$ for some $n$.  

Comment: Misha, I don't think that's not quite right. See this MO answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84950/metrizable-space/84974#84974

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a million examples. You should google "acyclic space". Here is one: if you remove a point from a homology sphere you get a manifold whose cohomology is trivial in positive degrees. Take a tubular neighbourhood of it in some $\mathbf R^n$ and you get an open domain.

Comment: If, for instance, I consider the Poincare' homology sphere, this is a particular 3-homology sphere (in particular not homeomorphic to the sphere) acyclic and noncontractible, thus a good example for my question.
But I think I have read somewhere that this object cannot be smoothly embeded in R^4, right?
How can I do in this case? Can I modify the object to have the embeding property but not changing the acyclic and the noncontractibility propreties?



Comment: Clearly, I refer to the punctured Poincare' homology sphere.

Comment: Every manifold embeds in some $\mathbf R^n$ (Whitney).